# How to figure out whether a key exists in guava cache so that I don't overwrite it?

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I have a guava cache and I want to figure out whether a particular key already exists or not so that I don't overwrite them? Is this possible to do with Guava cache?

```
private final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(1_000_000)
    .concurrencyLevel(100)
    .build()

// there is no put method like this
if (cache.put(key, value) != null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message for " + key + " already in queue");
}
```

Looks like there is no put method that returns boolean where I can figure out whether key already exists. Is there any other way by which I can figure out whether key already exists so that I don't overwrite it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Cache.asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap--) to treat your cache as a `Map`, thereby exposing additional functionality such as [`Map.put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), which returns the previously-mapped value:

```
if (cache.asMap().put(key, value) != null) {
```

But that will still replace the previous value. You might want to use [`putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) instead:

```
if (cache.asMap().putIfAbsent(key, value) != null) {
```

Comment: what is the difference between `cache.put` vs `cache.asMap().put` vs `cache.asMap().putIfAbsent`? What I mean is - In one case we use put directly on cache and in other it calls asMap() and then calls put on it?

Comment: @john `Map.put()` returns the previous value. See my update.

Comment: I found this note in the documentation: **Note that although the view is modifiable, no method on the returned map will ever cause entries to be automatically loaded.**